KMeans Clustering on GPU with Torch
I have a tensor x of shape [32, 10, 128], where:

32 is the batch size,

10 represents nodes,

128 denotes features per
node.


My objective is to compute node similarities based on their features across each batch input independently. Specifically, I aim to cluster nodes within each input using KMeans clustering on their feature similarities. The end goal is to aggregate nodes that are similar in feature space into clusters and then compute a representative average feature vector for each cluster.
Key requirements:

Perform KMeans clustering independently for each input.
Utilize Torch to leverage GPU acceleration effectively to execute all the batch inputs parallelly.

Let me give you my code:
def cluster_knn(x, cluster_num):

batch_size, num_nodes, num_features = x.shape
# Initialize a list to store cluster labels for each batch element
batch_cluster_labels = []

# Iterate over each batch element
for i in range(batch_size):
    # Extract data for the current batch element
    x_single = x[i]  # Shape [number of nodes, number of features] for current batch element

    # Reshape the input for clustering
    x_single_reshaped = x_single.view(num_nodes, num_features)

    # Convert to NumPy array
    x_single_np = x_single_reshaped.cpu().detach().numpy()


    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=cluster_num, random_state=0)
    cluster_labels_np = kmeans.fit_predict(x_single_np)

    # Append cluster labels for current batch element to the list
    batch_cluster_labels.append(torch.tensor(cluster_labels_np))


batch_cluster_labels = torch.stack(batch_cluster_labels).cuda()

return batch_cluster_labels


def merge_(x, batch_cluster_labels):

batch_size = x.shape[0]
all_batch_results = []
clustered_features = []
  
# Iterate over each batch element and its cluster labels
for i in range(batch_size):
    x_single = x[i]  # Shape [number of sensors, number of features] for current batch element
    labels_single = batch_cluster_labels[i]  # Cluster labels for current batch element

    # Determine unique clusters in current batch element
    unique_clusters = torch.unique(labels_single)


    # Initialize a list to store concatenated features for each cluster
    clustered_features = []
    
    # Iterate over each unique cluster
    for cluster in unique_clusters:
        # Find indices of nodes belonging to current cluster
        indices = torch.nonzero(labels_single == cluster).squeeze()
        
        # intialiize list to collect features for current cluster
        cluster_features_list = []
        # Handle both single and multiple nodes indices
        if indices.dim() == 0: # If indices is 0-dimensional, convert to list of one element 
            indices = indices.unsqueeze(0)
            

        for idx in indices:
            cluster_features_list.append(x_single[idx].unsqueeze(0))


        cluster_features_list = torch.cat(cluster_features_list, dim=0).reshape(len(cluster_features_list), -1)
        mean_features = torch.mean(cluster_features_list, dim=0)
        # Append concatenated features for current batch element to main list
        clustered_features.append(mean_features)
    
    # append clustered_features for current batch elemebt to all batch_resuls
    all_batch_results.append(clustered_features)
# stack the list into a tensor of shape [batc_size, number of cluster, each cluster features] 
tensor_result = torch.stack([torch.stack(batch, dim=0) for batch in all_batch_results], dim=0) 

return tensor_result

batch_cluster_labels = cluster_knn(x, cluster_num)
mrg_cluster_feat = merge_(x, batch_cluster_labels)

In my code, I am not getting the advantage of executing batch inputs in parallel. So this code execution is quite slow. Could someone guide me on how to implement this efficiently in Torch?
